# How to handle rejection so that Future.get() does not forever?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I played with Java's `ThreadPoolExecutor` class. Here is my code

```
public class MyReject {
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 
            50000L, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5));       
    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, ex) -> {
            System.out.println("Rejected!");                
        }
    );

    Task[] tasks = new Task[20];        
    Future<?>[] future = new Future[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        tasks[i] = new Task(40, "Task " + i);
        future[i] = executor.submit(tasks[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        try {
            System.out.println(future[i].get());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

        } 
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}
```

}

I see that some `future[i].get()` will wait forever because of the corresponding task is rejected early by the `executor`. How can I tell the `future[i].get()` that task has been rejected, so you don't want to wait any more?

Many thanks,
P.S. Supposed that I don't want to use `future[i].get(timeout, TimeUnit)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel the task in `RejectedExecutionHandler`, in which case it will throw `CancellationException` when you try to invoke `get` on rejected future.

`executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler((r, ex) -> {
            if (r instanceof FutureTask) {
                ((FutureTask) r).cancel(false);
            }
            System.out.println("Rejected!");
        });`

If you do not want to catch Exception, then you can create a custom attribute `rejected` in your Task class, and set it inside `RejectedExecutionHandler`. Before invoking Future.get () , check the `rejected` attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the call to `setRejectedExecutionHandler`, then `submit` will throw a `RejectedExecutionException` if the executor rejects the task.

Comment: Yes. If I remove the `setRejectedExecutionHandler`, the submit will throw a `RejectedExecutionException`, but the `future.get()` still wait forever on that rejected task.

Comment: Yes. But the idea is that you can use that information to avoid calling get() in the first place.